# Can you use both 3.3v and 5v

Tags: arduino-mega

Can you use an Arduino EtherMega's 3.3v and 5v pins with two sensors, one requiring 3.3v and the other 5v and a sketch that combines both?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. As long as you take into account that the outputs of the Arduino will be 5V so you may need to reduce that to 3.3V for the 3.3V sensor (if it has any connection to an output).